# AbstractMethodError with Akka 2.3.3 and Play 2.3.1

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, reactivemongo

I'm developing a Scala application using Play, Akka and ReactiveMongo.  Here are the specific libraries I'm using...

```
org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4
com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.3.1
com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.3
org.reactivemongo#reactivemongo_2.10;0.10.0
```

When my code makes an async call to the MongoDB collection, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Others have reported this exception when using Akka 2.3 with Play 2.2 but nothing with the versions I'm using.  The ReactiveMongoPlugin is successfully loaded.

Comment: It appears that upgrading to ReactiveMongo 0.11.0_SNAPSHOT fixes the problem.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the dependencies advertised by each library (except where you are certain about binary compatible updates). In this case reactivemongo_2.10 depends on Akka 2.2.1 (which is not binary compatible with 2.3.x). Mixing versions manually is very likely to result in such errors.

Comment: i have the same problem with akka 2.3.7 and reactivemongo 0.10.5-akka23. Did you find a solution?